# My global variable comes up as undefined in transcationSuccess callback - can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-sql

Im working with Sencha touch and I am trying to update a panel after I get the data from my webdb... wouldnt think this would be hard but I am totally missing something here...

```
var returnHTML = getPresentations();

function getPresentations() {
returnHTML = "<ul>";

db = openDatabase("myDB", "", "TheDB", 500000);     
db.transaction(
    function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT title FROM Presentations",
            [],
            function (transaction, results) {
                var returnHTML = "<ul>";
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    returnHTML += "<li>" + results.rows.item(i).title + '</li>';
                }
                returnHTML += "</ul>";
            },
            onError);
    },
        onTransactError,
        onTransactSuccess);
}

function onTransactSuccess() {
    alert(returnHTML);
    console.log(returnHTML);
    extPanel.update();
}
```

But `returnHTML` keeps coming back as undefined... not really sure what is happening here.

I watch it go through my SELECT function... its a complete string before its done.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues here. The first is an issue of scope. You're creating a new `returnHTML` within the scope of your function by using the `var` keyword. Remove the `var` keyword inside of your function so you're setting the previously created instance of `returnHTML`

**This:**

```
var returnHTML = "<ul>";
```

**Should be:**

```
returnHTML = "<ul>";
```

In addition, it appears that you're not actually returning the value of `returnHTML` from your function. Simply add `return returnHTML` to the end of your function.

```
...
},
        onTransactError,
        onTransactSuccess);

    //Add this line
    return returnHTML;
}
```

Comment: It's not so much an issue of scope as an issue of assigning the result of a function that doesn't return anything.

Comment: @TimRogers, I believe it's both an issue of scope and of the function not returning a result.

Comment: wow, i worked HARD at screwing this up... I wasn't returning anything because I am manipulating the global. since I was changing the global variable, it wouldnt matter.  But I can see how screwy this thing looks.

Answer (score 0):

On your first line, you are assigning the result of `getPresentations` to `returnHTML`. But you don't return a value from this function, so the result is `undefined`.

So either call the function to set the result into the global variable (i.e. remove the assignment), or return the result from the function and assign it (i.e. add a `return` statement to the function).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line also might need changing.

```
returnHTML += "<li>" + results.rows.item(i).title + '</li>';
```

To

```
returnHTML += "<li>" + results.rows.item(i).title + "</li>";
```

As i think double quotations and single quotations will have different meanings in this instance.

If anything to keep it consistant too.